# How to create a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I’m having a hard time trying to create this table for school.

set A TABLE WITH 100 ROWS, Each Row HAS 2 COLUMNS, COLUMN 1 IS AN IDENTITY COLUMN, COLUMN 2 IS A RANDOM LETTER (THIS COLUMN IS 6 CHARACTERS WIDE) THEN UPDATE THE THE ROWS FROM 33 TO 68 AND MAKE THEM = TO YOUR INITIALS.

Comment: I see no attempt here or even an actual question? Try doing it yourself and if you run into a issue, post a question for that exact issue.

Comment: Edit your post so it's not all uppercase in the last part.

Comment: Helpful feedback: the downvotes are likely to come from (a) the all-caps shouting; and (b) no apparent attempt. It is possible that you have tried something (because you report you are "having a hard time") and if this is so, why not show what trouble you are actually having? Do you get an error? What code are you trying? Readers are keen to encourage all question authors here to try _something_ prior to posting. A good start would be a working `CREATE TABLE` statement that creates the two columns.

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you an example where I make a table with 4 rows and I update the rows from 2 to 3 and make them equal to my initials which are 'JTM'.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    random_string VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO my_table (random_string) VALUES(substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', FLOOR(RAND()*26)+1, 1));
INSERT INTO my_table (random_string) VALUES(substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', FLOOR(RAND()*26)+1, 1));
INSERT INTO my_table (random_string) VALUES(substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', FLOOR(RAND()*26)+1, 1));
INSERT INTO my_table (random_string) VALUES(substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', FLOOR(RAND()*26)+1, 1));
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;

| id  | random_string |
| --- | ------------- |
| 1   | C             |
| 2   | X             |
| 3   | F             |
| 4   | K             |
```

---

**Query #2**

```
UPDATE my_table SET random_string = 'JTM' WHERE id >= 2 AND id <= 3;
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #3**

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;

| id  | random_string |
| --- | ------------- |
| 1   | C             |
| 2   | JTM           |
| 3   | JTM           |
| 4   | K             |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fd6P1YhDSbfc3PFxaCeLFd/0)